# iOS: Detect when my UIView is add in other view

Tags: ios, uiview, superview

```
CustomView *customView = [...];
[self.view addSubview:customView];
```

I need to detect in my CustomView class when it is added in other views or when my superview changes.

Comment: did/willMoveToSuperview: are not enough?

Comment: Not when customView is added in other views.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use `willMoveToSuperview:` and `didMoveToSuperview` to detect when the view is moved around. `layoutSubviews` will be called when the superview changes frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had not thought of layoutSubviews.

Comment: Question: in my view controller, `viewWillAppear:animated` is called *before* `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. So even if I use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to arrange my views based on the superview's size, I cannot start some animations *after that* in `viewWillAppear:animated` where they belong. How should this be done?

Comment: Second method name is `didMoveToSuperview` (without the `:`), just in case anyone copy/pastes.

Answer (score 7):

- For a UIView use `- (void)didMoveToSuperview`
- For a UIViewController use `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

Answer (score -5):

also assign THE TAG of Customview before addsubview and the detect by Particular TAG.

Comment: Not a bad strategy if you want to keep track of the view from the superview's perspective with the `viewWithTag:` method, but that wasn't the question here.